Unable to Access MediaMTX WebRTC Stream in Minikube Kubernetes Cluster
Mediamtx webrtc stream is not accessible while running inside k8s cluster in minikube
I am facing an issue while trying to access a MediaMTX WebRTC stream that is deployed inside a Minikube Kubernetes cluster. The deployment seems to be set up correctly, but I cannot access the WebRTC stream, and I am getting a timeout error when trying to establish a connection.
Steps to Replicate the Issue:

Create a Minikube Cluster: Set up a Minikube cluster using the default configuration.

Deploy MediaMTX: Deploy the following resources: a Deployment, a Service, and a ConfigMap.


The Config map include custom mediamtx.yml config
Mediamtx Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mediamtx
  labels:
    app: mediamtx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mediamtx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mediamtx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mediamtx
        image: bluenviron/mediamtx
        args: ["/mediamtx.yml"] # Explicitly specify the config file location
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /mediamtx.yml
          subPath: mediamtx.yml
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8554
        - containerPort: 1935
        - containerPort: 8888
        - containerPort: 8889
        - containerPort: 8890
        - containerPort: 8189
        env:
        - name: MTX_PROTOCOLS
          value: "tcp"
        - name: MTX_WEBRTCADDITIONALHOSTS
          value: "172.19.0.1" # Adjust as needed
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: mediamtx-config
          defaultMode: 0644  # Ensure the file is readable

Mediamtx Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mediamtx
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: rtsp
      port: 8554
      targetPort: 8554
      protocol: TCP
    - name: rtmp
      port: 1935
      targetPort: 1935
      protocol: TCP
    - name: web
      port: 8888
      targetPort: 8888
      protocol: TCP
    - name: web-rtc
      port: 8889
      targetPort: 8889
      protocol: TCP
    - name: rtsp-udp
      port: 8890
      targetPort: 8890
      protocol: UDP
    - name: udp-extra
      port: 8189
      targetPort: 8189
      protocol: UDP
  selector:
    app: mediamtx

mediamtx config map
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mediamtx-config
data:
  mediamtx.yml: |
    paths:
      mycamera:
        source: rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.101.215:554/unicaststream/1


The Config map includes custom mediamtx configuration. I have added a default rtsp stream path entry to it, And trying to access the corresponding webrtc streams.

Apply all resources, wait for medamtx pod to start. Expose mediamtx service using kubectl port-forward

Now the webrtc stream should be accessible at http://localhost:8889/mycamera, But I am not able to access it


Server Logs
Mediamtx server logs before trying to access webrtc stream
2024/09/24 06:49:37 INF MediaMTX v1.9.0
2024/09/24 06:49:37 INF configuration loaded from /mediamtx.yml
2024/09/24 06:49:37 INF [path matrixcamera] [RTSP source] started
2024/09/24 06:49:37 INF [RTSP] listener opened on :8554 (TCP)
2024/09/24 06:49:37 INF [RTMP] listener opened on :1935
2024/09/24 06:49:37 INF [HLS] listener opened on :8888
2024/09/24 06:49:37 INF [WebRTC] listener opened on 0.0.0.0:8889 (HTTP), :8189 (ICE/UDP)
2024/09/24 06:49:37 INF [SRT] listener opened on :8890 (UDP)
2024/09/24 06:49:37 INF [path matrixcamera] [RTSP source] ready: 2 tracks (H264, G711)
Mediamtx server logs after trying to access webrtc stream
2024/09/24 07:15:24 INF [WebRTC] [session 8b9d0424] created by 127.0.0.1:52060
2024/09/24 07:15:34 INF [WebRTC] [session 8b9d0424] closed: deadline exceeded while waiting connection
I am trying to access the stream at localhost:8889/mycamera after running kubectl port-forward svc/mediamtx 8889:8889
I also tried adding stun/turn server in mediamtx config
# webrtcICEServers2:
# - url: stun:stun2.1.google.com:19302

Also tried adding webrtc address as broadcast in mediamtx config
# rtspAddress: 0.0.0.0:8554

Still I am unable to acesss I get following errrors in browser console
DELETE http://localhost:8889/matrixcamera/whep/adcf8e30-a171-4843-bfa0-8b2522b86abe 404 (Not Found)
onError @ matrixcamera/:368
onConnectionState @ matrixcamera/:490
pc.oniceconnectionstatechange @ matrixcamera/:515
favicon.ico:1

The whep DELETE request always timesout
